# Por que no funciona str_split con este string?

Tags: r, rstudio, split, str-replace

Usando la funcion str_split, no me funciona cuando intento separar por "$"

```s
> str_split(s, pattern = "$")
[1] "$9,888"

# The output
[[1]]
[1] "$9,888"
```

Cuando quiero esto :

```
"$" "9,888"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, es por esto, hay carácteres que son especiales y necesitan poner "\" delante

```
String cadena = "$9,888";
String[] trozos = cadena.split("\\$");
String t1 = trozos[0]; //
String t2 = trozos[1]; //9,888
```

Comment: Me referia a la funcion split, ya modifique la pregunta